# Lost word in first page

Tags: captions, packages

I have a matter with an article, in the first page it appears `caption`, as word, alone. The rest of the pdf looks as I want. I have searched everywhere but I do not know where does it come from. I guess, it is a matter of compatibility between packages, but I am not sure, I have tried all, even putting and taking packages out. Any comment will be helpful, the script looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{natbib} 

\hbadness=10000\hfuzz=50pt

\usepackage{StyleFiles/watermark}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eucal}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{grffile} 

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\newcounter {subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection .\@alph\c@subsubsubsection}
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*{\subsubsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\makeatother


\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\onehalfspacing

\setcounter{footnote}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


\title{} 
\author{} 
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle \end{center}


\tableofcontents


Body
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not compilable. Do you really need all those packages? Please make an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) You really shouldn't have subsubsubsections, unless you are writing law or something like that. Have a look at the `book` or report-class. These gives you `chapter` and `part`, which goes above `section`

Comment: Edit: didn't notice @runartrollet posted as I was typing. I suppose just to explain his comment then, a MWE will give you a more specific answer to help your situation. If you remove all the packages and add them one-by-one until the problem starts you can figure out which packages are conflicting, at which point others will be able to give specifics for solving that conflict.

Comment: Thanks, I already have done that: remove all the packages and add them one-by-one. However, the resuIt does not make sense, because the problem starts with the very basic packages. Regarding your comment, @runartrollet, I have included the subsubsubsection posibility because the text requires it, since it is a very academic one. Maybe, I should reorder the text and make it more simple . I guessed that by experience someone could know what is happening or has had the same case.

Comment: We cannot just guess. For all we know, the reason for why `caption` is appearing, might be because you simply forgot to put the slash before `caption`. We need to be able to reproduce your error.

Comment: You are right, @runartrollet, you should always be able to reproduce the case. Nonetheless, the text is big and it won be congruent to put it here. THe fact that  `caption` appears alone in the first page, already tell me something. I have searched many times, if it was just a missing `slash`. But I have not found any problem. Because of that, I thought it was a problem with any package conflict, something that happens.

Comment: In the past I have experienced similar problems, that have to do with package conflict. So as I told, I have followed the normal procedure by inserting one per one, again. I think, I just will simplify the packages requirement and continue looking for any mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*First of all: Please do not ignore error messages you get when compiling your document.*

The example document can be minimized to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
Body
\end{document}
```

It still shows the magic "caption", but issues an error message:

```
! Package ctable Error: You must load ctable after tikz.

See the ctable package documentation for explanation.
```

It helps following the advice, i.e. changing the package load order. This one compiles without error and doesn't show "caption":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}
Body
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  @Axel Sommerfeldt, you were right, I was missing the right order of packages. Somehow, I missed this error message. I will put more attention on that.